# SQL Server tables not showing without schema [Jetbrains Datagrip]

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, datagrip

Whenever I create tables they don't show on the side database explorer. I always have to create a schema first under the database and then:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.TABLENAME(.....)
```

I find this kind of annoying, tables do exist and you can call them but they just won't show on the side explorer if they are not under some schema. Is this normal on DataGrip?

Comment: Nevermind, just tried to create a schema called "dbo" under the database, executed, got an error saying i don't have permission. After that a dbo schema automatically appeared under my database with all the tables, weird...

Comment: whenever you will not specify schema while creating a table, it will default create under dbo schema. If you will specify the schema name, it will create under that schema. If table exist but it is not showing in SQL Explorer then you need to right click and refresh the table node to see the newly created tables.

Comment: @MukeshArora That is statement is incorrect. A object created without a specified schema will be created in the current user's **default schema**. That default is often "dbo" but it can be set to anything.

Comment: Weird, do you still experience the issue?